# Cannot remove element from HTML in Flutter

Tags: javascript, html, flutter

I am following the [guide for customizing web application initialization in Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/initialization#example-display-a-progress-indicator), and I want to remove the loading indicator when the Flutter engine has started, however it does not seem to do anything.

We the Flutter app starts nothing happens, and the indicator is still in the background.

Here is a simplified version of my index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!--
      If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
      href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

      The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
      it to work correctly.

      For more details:
      * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

      This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
      the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
-->
    <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
    <title>My App</title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icons/favicon.png" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
</head>

<body class="main">
    <!-- Splash screen loading -->
    <div id="loading">
        <style>
            body {
                inset: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                position: fixed;
            }

            #loading {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                height: 100%;
                justify-content: center;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #loading img {
                opacity: 1;
                max-width: 350px;
                margin: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <img src="icons/splash-icon.png" alt="Loading indicator" />
    </div>
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <!-- This script installs service_worker.js to provide PWA functionality to
       application. For more information, see:
       https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers -->
    <script>
        // Service workers are supported. Use them.
        window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
            // Download main.dart.js
            _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
                serviceWorker: {
                    serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
                },
                onEntrypointLoaded: async function (engineInitializer) {
                    // Initialize the Flutter engine
                    let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine();

                    // Remove the splash screen loading.
                    document.getElementById("loading").remove();

                    // Run the app
                    await appRunner.runApp();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I have tried using different selectors, hiding the element and removing it from the parent.

Comment: are you sure is that the loading indicator is html. ? i don't think so. as flutter does all in one canvas.

Comment: Flutter web takes over the whole HTML page by default, but the renderer should just be  another element compatible with other HTML elements. Which means that you can display elements on top or bellow (like in my example where the loading is bellow). The problem I have is that I am not able to remove it.

Comment: you can' t be so sure about that. You must have used browser dev tools. all the hover effects what we see are made using a canvas. do you think you can display above dev tools? no. same way i don't think flutter allows this much freedom.

Comment: I was able to find a solution myself, see my answer. Flutter do allows for that type of customization, in a sense that it is placed in your HTML. You could even run the application in a different element using the `hostElement` as indicated in the [documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/platform-integration/web/initialization#initializing-the-engine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by recreating the web support for my app with the latest Flutter version.

```bash
flutter create . --platforms=web
```

I then added in the index.html the "loading" HTML element, resulting in the following file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <!--
      If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
      href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

      The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
      it to work correctly.

      For more details:
      * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

      This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
      the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
-->
    <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">
    <title>My App</title>

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="icons/favicon.png" />

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>

    <title>My App</title>
    <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

    <script>
        // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
        var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    </script>
    <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
    <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body class="main">
    <!-- Splash screen loading -->
    <div id="loading">
        <style>
            body {
                inset: 0;
                overflow: hidden;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                position: fixed;
            }

            #loading {
                align-items: center;
                display: flex;
                height: 100%;
                justify-content: center;
                width: 100%;
            }

            #loading img {
                opacity: 1;
                max-width: 350px;
                margin: 20px;
            }
        </style>
        <img src="icons/splash-icon.png" alt="Loading indicator" />
    </div>

    <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function (ev) {
            // Download main.dart.js
            _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
                serviceWorker: {
                    serviceWorkerVersion: serviceWorkerVersion,
                },
                onEntrypointLoaded: function (engineInitializer) {
                    // Initialize the Flutter engine
                    engineInitializer.initializeEngine().then(function = (appRunner) {

                        // Remove the "loading" div element, if any.
                        document.getElementById('loading')?.remove();

                        // Run the app
                        appRunner.runApp();
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The main change seem to be to the how serviceWorkerVersion and Flutter initialization are handled. The following script is no loger used:

```html
    <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
```

And is replaced by these scripts in the :

```
    <script>
        // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
        var serviceWorkerVersion = null;
    </script>
    <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
    <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
```